# Testing CO₂ for cell culture

Tags: cell-culture

I'm am refurbishing some old CO<sub>2</sub> incubators. I would like to test the precision of the CO<sub>2</sub> sensor. There is a sample port on this incubator.

What sorts of  methods are commonly used to measure CO<sub>2</sub> in these incubators?

Strangely, the manufacturer of the incubator makes no recommendations.

I need to be able to report the measurement as a percentage.

Comment: I would presume calibrating it with a known gas concentrations is what they do at the factory. In my lab, the calibration is done by the servicing company.

Comment: Chemistry SE might be able to come up with a simple way get some known concentrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:

http://www.mybacharach.com/fyrite-gas-analyzers.htm

Probably what I need